# How do I use Proc Transpose to flip my data from several rows into columns?

Tags: csv, sas, transpose, proc

I'm working with a CSV file that contains survey information. An example of the data would be this:

[Original Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf2r2.png)
[image]

I'm looking to write a Proc Transpose in SAS to change all of the data so it's in one row with new columns so it looks like this:

[Transposed Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5tZg.png)
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TRANSPOSE` should be

```
by Survey_ID Question_Num;
id Key_2;
var Value;
```